# Example of writing shadow rules using Snakemake

Tags: snakemake

Let's suppose I have a snakemake rule as follows:

```
rule ExampleNoShadow:
    input:
        inFile = "{runPath}/{sample}_inFile.txt",
        otherFile = "/some/other/directory/otherFile.txt"
    output:
        outFile1 = "{runPath}/{sample}_outFile.txt",
        outFile2 = "{runPath}/{sample}_otherFile.txt"
    shell:
        """
        cd {wildcards.runPath}
        cp {wildcards.sample}_inFile.txt {wildcards.sample}_outFile.txt
        cp {input.otherFile} {wildcards.sample}_otherFile.txt
        cd ..
        """
```

How would I write this rule with `shadow: "shallow"`, `shadow: "minimal"`, and `shadow: "full"`, and how would this change the execution of said rule?  It isn't entirely clear to me based on the documentation (https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html?highlight=shadow#shadow-rules; yes, I have looked at it).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand the question, but as the [docs](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#shadow-rules) indicate you can put the shadow key word in the rule like so:

```
rule NAME:
    input: "path/to/inputfile"
    output: "path/to/outputfile"
    shadow: "shallow"  # <------ here!
    shell: "somecommand --other_outputs other.txt {input} {output}"
```

How it would change:

> By setting shadow: "shallow", the top level files and directories are symlinked, so that any relative paths in a subdirectory will be real paths in the filesystem. The setting shadow: "full" fully shadows the entire subdirectory structure of the current workdir. The setting shadow: "minimal" only symlinks the inputs to the rule. Once the rule successfully executes, the output file will be moved if necessary to the real path as indicated by output.

Comment: I was hoping to have an example of how the same rule would look with each shadow option.  I can read the documentation, it just isn't entirely clear to me based on the documentation how referencing files (particularly files that are located elsewhere on the system, rather than in a sub-directory) in a shell script works.  Especially since my actual use case often constructs the path to a program in a different directory based on the path to the Snakefile, and that program is not an input, but is rather assumed to be there based on the presence of the Snakefile.